# Facebook iFrame application -- IE7 not allowing cookies

Tags: facebook, iframe, internet-explorer-7, session-cookies

I know this topic has been covered extensively, but I am totally stuck and in need of some direction and new opinions.  I have a Facebook iFrame application that works perfectly in IE6,8, Safari, Chrome, FF, etc.  Only IE7 gives me grief.

I have created a P3P policy file, and its associated XML file.  The policy fully validates with the P3P policy validator.

As soon as the iFrame loads from within Facebook, the red eye icon appears and when I click it, it reports that cookies from the iFrame's domain are blocked.  I have confirmed that the default 'medium' privacy setting is set on IE7.  Interestingly I've found that by removing Google Analytics, the page will load initially without blocking the cookies, but as soon as the page reloads, or the user logs in, cookies are then blocked again even though the P3P header is sent immediately from every page.  All assets are sent via S3, so there shouldn't be any issues there.

FYI, here's my P3P file; I've tried absolute paths, relative paths, switching order of CP and policyref, and separated the two into separate header calls with no luck.

```
header('P3P: CP="NON DSP TAIa PSAa PSDa OUR IND UNI", policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml"');
```

I have confirmed that the P3P Header is being sent and received by the browser.  I have added a META p3p tag to the HTML page.  I have removed all redirects.  Still the issue persists.  I've spent so much time looking into this, and I am now out of ideas.  Any thoughts or ideas about how to approach this from a fresh perspective would be greatly appreciated.  I'm using PHP 5.3.5 over NGINX.  No framework being used...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Facebook iframe app worked great in all browsers except IE7. When you first went to the app it loaded fine. But then when you clicked a link it would load the page okay but then after a second or so would refresh and redirect the browser. In the end you just got a blank page. I also had the red eye icon blocking the cookies.

The culprit turned out to be the javascript code which loads the facebook javascript lib:

```
FB.init({
            appId  : '<?=FACEBOOK_APP_ID?>',
            status : true, // check login status
            cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
        });
```

To fix the problem I changed status : true, to status : false. Now when clicking links the page loads and doesn't refresh.

So whats really going on here I am not sure but I have a guess...The redirect was being caused by the FB javavascript checking the login status and for some reason thinking the user was logged out and so redirecting to a login page. The server side login script I guess would then see that you had indeed logged in and redirect you back to the app. So on and so on.

So the problem of IE7 not setting the cookies set inside the iframe still exists, the evil eye remains. But as long as the links inside your iframe reference the parent window target="_top" pointing at the facebook canvas page it seems you don't need the cookie anyway. The PHP SDK looks for the session in a number of places starting with $_REQUEST. I am guessing that when facebook loads the iframe it includes the session param in the query string. So even though the cookies don't work in IE7 through the iframe your server scripts will still get them from the query param.

Hope that makes some sort of sense, I don't totally get it but it fixed my app.

Comment: Hi Peter: very interesting, thanks for your explanation.  Unfortunately our requests are being made via AJAX, so the hard-refreshes are not an option.  What we ultimately did was store the necessary data in a JSON object, and validated that data upon submission if we had a valid session, and otherwise (ie7), submitted the data.  Since the app was only live for a short time, we weren't too concerned about falsified data.  

We also use the JS SDK to kill invalid sessions (only way since FB status cookies are managed through their domain), so couldn't go this route for that reason as well.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know but maybe this will help, it worked like a charm on my app.

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
ob_start();
session_start();
```